# Necessity of the locks while working with concurrent hash map

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

Here is the code in one of my classes:

```
 class SomeClass {

   private Map<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   private volatile int counter = 0;
   final AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0); // will be used in other classes/threads too
   private ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();

   public void put(String some) {
    l.lock();
    try {
        int tmp = Integer.parseInt(some);
        map.put(counter++, tmp);
        sum.getAndAdd(tmp);
    } finally {
        l.unlock();
    }
   }

   public Double get() {
    l.lock();
    try {
        //... perform some map resizing operation ...
        // some calculations including sum field ...
    } finally {
        l.unlock();
    }
   }

}
```

You can assume that this class will be used in concurrent environment.

The question is: how do you think is there a necessity of the locks? How does this code smell? :)

Comment: Since you're updating multiple things in the put (the map, the counter, the sum), you need to ensure exclusive access to ensure they are updated consistently. Additionally, the `counter++` isn't atomic.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, but I'm performing increment with already acquired monitor, right?

Comment: Yes. And I'm saying that's necessary.

Comment: Regarding your last question, it smells horrible. `new ConcurrentHashMap()` is using a *raw type*, `new AtomicInteger(0L)` does not even compile, the comment “will be used in other classes” contradicts the `private` modifier, and generally, the purpose is of this code is not clear, but it looks like not doing whatever you intended. As said by Andy Turner, querying a monotonically increasing counter as map key will never find a mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the operations inside `public void put(String some)`.

1. `map.put(counter++, tmp);`
2. `sum.getAndAdd(tmp);`

Now let's look at the individual parts.

1. `counter` is a volatile variable. So it only provides memory visibility but not atomicity. Since `counter++` is a compound operation, you need a lock to achieve atomicity.
2. `map.put(key, value)` is atomic since it is a `ConcurrentHashMap`.
3. `sum.getAndAdd(tmp)` is atomic since it is a `AtomicInteger`.

As you can see, except `counter++` every other operation is atomic. However, you are trying to achieve some function by combining all these operations. To achieve atomicity at the functionality level, you need a lock. This will help you to avoid surprising side effects when the threads interleave between the individual atomic operations.

So you need a lock because `counter++` is not atomic and you want to combine a few atomic operations to achieve some functionality (*assuming* you want this to be atomic).

Comment: thanks a lot! What if I convert volatile counter to atomic integer, will it still make sense to have external locks? I guess yes, because as you mentioned, we need to maintain functional consistency overall.

Comment: Yes. Even If you make the `counter` atomic, to maintain functional consistency you need locks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always increment `counter` when you use it as a key to put into this map:

```
map.put(counter++, tmp);
```

when you come to read it again:

```
return sum / map.get(counter);
```

`map.get(counter)` will be `null`, so this results in a NPE (unless you put more than 2^32 things into the map, ofc). (I'm assuming you mean `sum.get()`, otherwise it won't compile).

As such, you can have equivalent functionality without any locks:

```
class SomeClass {
  public void put(String some) { /* do nothing */ }
  public Double get() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
}
```

---

You've not really fixed the problem with your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55375557/2). `divisor` will still be null, so the equivalent functionality without locks would be:

```
class SomeClass {
  private final AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public void put(String some) {
    sum.getAndAdd(Integer.parseInt(some));
  }

  public Double get() {
    return sum.get();
  }
}
```